# Expandable Vertical Navigation Menu in SAPUI5 (sap.m)

Tags: html, sapui5

Does SAPUI5 have anything like shown in the example in the sap.m library -- [check here](http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/verticalnav/index.html).

Something like an Accordian (sap.ui.commons.Accordion), but in sap.m library and not sap.ui.commons due to 'text' size issue (and other unknowns).

I am looking for something similar, so that in the master/detail view, instead of navigating on click on the 'master' item to another list, I can just 'expand' the list (as all the menu details is fetched from server in one single JSON).

If this doesn't exists, does it make sense to extend StandardListItem or ListItemBase? Or I should use the standard approach of 'clicking in the master list --> navigate to new set of list --> click on that opens up the details page'?

Regards,

A.

Comment: Found sap.m.Panel - [Click Here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.PanelExpanded/preview) - Even though this doesn't match exactly (on-hover-auto-expand) -- is the approach fine in using this in the 'Master Area' of SplitApp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Accordion control in the sap.m library but you can combine a few other controls to reach a similar goal.

For example, the sap.m.Panel has an "expandable" flag that allows to open and close the panel content. 
With a few simple simple functions to connect the panels to eachother (close all others when you open one) you can do it. I'm afraid only the hover will not be possible by standard API calls.

Also the sap.m.Carousel can be an option for displaying multiple pages of content in a horizontal way in the content area.

These are the standard patterns that we defined for interaction. If you want to be completely flexible, you can always extend a UI5 control or write your own control to do such a behavior. This might be a lot more work though.

Cheers